# Modulus operator confusing

Tags: python, modulo

Can someone please explain what the code below "if not epoch%display n epoch" means? My understanding is that if epoch / display has NO remainder, then print the statement. Could someone clarify this for me?

```
if not epoch%display_n_epoch:
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Train Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Test Loss: {test_loss:.3f} ")
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct. It is hard to guess at the intent of this code without more context.

Comment: `if epoch % display_n_epoch == 0:` would be clearer than relying on the fact that `not 0` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that it would be hard understanding the printed text due to lack of context, the module operator `%` in python simply returns the remainder of a division:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 3
>>> a % b
2
```

In python every non-zero number is treated as a boolean `True` in `if` condition:

```
>>> bool(2)
True
>>> bool(-1)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

In your case, your condition is true, and thus the phrase is printed, when `epoch%display_n_epoch` returns zero (the `not` inverts the processed boolean equivalent value).